# Dual boot and the files /boot/grub/grub.cfg -- which one is used?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Say, I have 2 linux systems. They both of them have `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but the one that's used on boot is from one of them. There's no `/boot` partition. How is it determined which `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` should be used and how change that?

I have 1 physical disk, 2 partitions and UEFI/GPT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear from your question but I believe:

- Assuming we have **two physical disks**, it'll depend on where BIOS/UEFI is looking. Otherwise known as the boot order. This is slightly different with UEFI because the installer talks directly to the system to install its shim, but you could have two systems with two separate UEFI shims installed. The order is decided by the system at boot.
- Assuming **two partitions on one physical disk with BIOS**, it'll depend on who wrote to the MBR (master boot record, beginning portion of the disk) last (at install, or since you ran `install-grub`). They can overwrite each other if you reinstall grub. `update-grub` should only update the local configuration.
- Assuming **two partitions, one physical disk, UEFI**, both should be able to co-exist peacefully. You'll get a pick of order at boot at the system level, and each bootloader might know about the other one but they aren't competing for one MBR.

Comment: `update-grub` does not touch the MBR (it just regenerates `grub.cfg`), `grub-install` does.

Comment: @fkraiem Interesting point, thank you. Updated.

Comment: `. You'll get a pick of order at boot at the system level,` -- where? what determines which grud is used?

Comment: @OskarK. Every BIOS I've ever used has had some sort of boot order selection, either in the setup screen or as an optional *PRESS F12 TO SELECT BOOT DEVICE* screen. Or, commonly both.

Comment: you didn't understand my question. how does bios know what OS are there installed? When I boot, I see the boot menu from Ubunut which contains "Ubuntu, Windows, Arch" items for booting. Why is the grub from exactly Ubuntu and not from Arch used?

Comment: BIOS or UEFI is linking to *that* copy of grub because that's either the priority disk in BIOS/UEFI, or it's installed in the MBR (BIOS) and the other isn't —they can't coexist— or it's the top entry in the UEFI partition. As I've said in my answer what is actually happening this is highly dependent on the hardware being used.

Comment: see my update. also "or it's the top entry in the UEFI partition." -- how to change that?

Comment: In the setup screens you see at boot

Comment: My BIOS setup screen only shows one `Ubuntu` to boot even though there are three partitions on the same SSD with `grub.cfg` to choose from. I found that the last partition installed is the one which `grub.cfg` file is read. I would like to create a menu to pick which of the three grub uses. Like OP I have UEFI/GPT setup. I have a hunch OP would also benefit from a menu to select which `grub.cfg` grub uses.

Comment: @fkraiem for the win! This solves the issue when dual-booting with OSes on different drives.

Answer (score 0):

I have three distributions on one SSD. The setup is UEFI/GPT. Whenever a new distribution is installed it takes control of grub.

To get the desired `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to be in control, boot with that distribution and use:

```bash
$ sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid 8337e8c8-6461-44f2-b5fe-dfd5b6b05883 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

$ sudo grub-install
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

$ sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
search.fs_uuid b40b3925-70ef-447f-923e-1b05467c00e7 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

- The first `cat` reveals Ubuntu 19.04 grub is used on `8337e8c8-6461-44f2-b5fe-dfd5b6b05883`
- The `grub-install` command will override that with the booted distributions `UUID`
- The last `cat` reveals Ubuntu 16.04 grub is now used on `b40b3925-70ef-447f-923e-1b05467c00e7`.
- From now on only Ubuntu 16.04 `update-grub` command will change the grub boot menu. Running `update-grub` in Ubuntu 19.04 will changes it's local copy of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but not effect the boot menu.

---

I've created a script to give more meaningful names to grub menu options:

```bash
sed -i "s|Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)|Windows 10|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed -i "s|Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)|Windows 10 original|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed -i "s|Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (16.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p7)|Broken Ubuntu 16.04|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sed -i "s|Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p10)|Ubuntu 19.04|g" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Now a grub menu options change from:

```bash
2. Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p10)
3. Advanced options for Ubuntu 19.04 (19.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p10)
```

to:

```bash
2. Ubuntu 19.04
3. Advanced options for Ubuntu 19.04
```